# How can I add ON DELETE constraint on the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add ON DELETE constraint on the table?

Answer (score 78):

Use ALTER TABLE+ADD CONSTRAINT. E.g. if you want to link tables members and profiles by member_id and cascade delete profiles each time the member is deleted, you can write something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE profiles
   ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_test`
   FOREIGN KEY (`member_id` )
   REFERENCES `members` (`member_id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

If you will need to update that constraint - you'll have to remove it at then create again, there's no direct way to alter it.

```
ALTER TABLE profiles DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_test`
```

Comment: Was not aware that you could not alter a foreign key but you had to recreate it. Saved me a lot of time thank you!

Comment: Used this for "on UPDATE cascade" too and worked fine (quite obviously). Used for a massive update on many constrained tables.

Comment: Do you know if PostgreSQL let to perform this alter without remove foreign before?

Answer (score -5):

If the foreign key is already created, there is a trick that worked for me.
You can modified the dump of your database and import it again with the modifications.

If you are using Mysql and Linux shell, it'd be like this:

First, export your database:

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p <namedatabase> > database.sql
```

Then, open the database.sql file and look for the table you want to alter.

Add `ON DELETE CASCADE` at the end of the foreign key sentence and save it.

Second, import your database with the modifications:

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p <namedatabase> < database.sql
```

And you will have your ON DELETE CASCADE working.

Comment: This is a really dangerous solution

Comment: Or you can disable foreign key checks, alter your constraint and turn them back on, without the overhead of reimporting the entire database.